# How to make machine learning model with One multiple value feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy

I would like to train a machine learning model with several features as input as X[] and with one output as Y. For example Every sample has a Data frame like this:
`X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4], Y`

Let's say One sample the followings Data is only one value:
`X[0], X[1], X[2], X[4], Y`
This is normal machine training problem.

But now, if I would like to set X[3] multiple values for example sample 1 Data is:

```
X[0] | X[1] | X[2] |         X[3]         | X[4] | Y
 10  |  5   |   6  | [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] |  7   | 90
```

Data in sample 2 is:

```
X[0] | X[1] | X[2] |         X[3]         | X[4] | Y
 11  |  7   |   5  | [20, 30, 40, 50, 60] |  3   | 80
```

Is this possible to follow the normal machine training process and got a model which could calculate a sample with other example with Data like:

```
X[0]   | X[1] |  X[2]  |         X[3]         | X[4] | Y
 10.5  |  6   |   5.5  | [15, 25, 35, 45, 55] |  5   | ???
```

If the length for each X[3] is not long, it is possible to divide the X[3] into multiple new features, but if the length of X[3] is very long (len > 1000) with different distribution, making binary is also lead to too many new features. Is there any way to treat the X[3] directly without adding new features?

Comment: If `Y` is numerical, search for Regression machine learning algorithms.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to read this post on how to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: The question is more relevant to this stack: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, should I move this question to the datascience site?

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing is to try taking the mean or median of X[3] and replace X[3] with its mean or median. Then train a normal machine learning model using updated data.

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends very much on the task you are pursuing.

Main approaches:

- convert `X3` to one values (use `mean`, `median`, `sum`) or multiple features (`min`, `max`, `stdev`, `quantiles`),
- `PCA` or another dimension reduction algorithm for to reduce the dimension inside,
- for free text features use `embedding` methods.

*Note*: I would recommend first checking whether you are throwing out important data by replacing the X3 vector with a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the data dictionary? What is X[3]? It will always be good to understand what that feature stands for and accordingly do a transformation that makes contextual sense.
In general, you can split that feature into 2 - length and some aggregation like sum, mean, median. Or even multiple features, but it is important to understand the meaning of the feature to decide which transformation or aggregation makes more sense.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29969749)